# Como Instalar Python3 Idle junto com Python 3.5.2 no Raspbian?

Tags: python-3.x

**Olá, tudo bem ?
Tenho tentado instalar o Python  3 IDLE com versão Python 3.5.2 no Raspbian, possuo um Raspberry 4b. Acontece que há duas versões que aparece 2.7 e 3.7 do Thorn IDLE. segui os passos das informações da programação abaixo :**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
cd $HOME
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.5.2.tgz
cd Python-3.5.2
./configure  
make -j4        
sudo make install
```

porém quando instala a idle com esses comandos :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 idle3
```

não aparece para ser executada. Se instalar primeiro a Idle do Python 3, fica coma versão 3.7. Como faço a IDLE Python 3 funcionar para a versão 3.5.2 neste caso ?

O objetivo final é poder rodar um programa desenvolvido em Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Agora você teria 3 versões diferente do python.

Poderia instalar um simulador de ambiente, controlando qual versão ira usar.

Tente usar pacotes .deb

Aqui alguns [https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-main-i386/idle-python3.5_3.5.1-10_all.deb.html)